# mcrypt install on mac with MAMP 5.1 (php7.2)

Tags: php, mcrypt, pecl, mamp-pro

Im trying to get the mcrypt module installed on mac, with php version 7.2.
I tried installing with pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1, but its giving me the following error:

```
pecl/mcrypt requires PHP (version >= 7.2.0, version <= 7.3.0, excluded versions: 7.3.0), installed version is 7.1.16
No valid packages found
install failed
```

But when I check my php  version with php-v I get this:

```
PHP 7.2.8 (cli) (built: Aug 28 2018 16:32:29) ( NTS )
```

I already tried to update my php.ini file with this:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303"
extension=mcrypt.so
```

And restarted apache but php -m doesn't show the mcrypt module.

Any clues why?

Comment: try to compile it from source, however just for curiosity why do you want to install mcrypt? you have to [avoid it](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong)

Comment: Because im running a local site that's running craft, and it requires mcrypt to run .. @hassan